# How to have a router connect to a wireless network with a captive gateway portal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My office has several companies which must connect to a wireless network for internet.  There is a captive gateway portal which requires a username/pw to login.  I'm not sure if this affects my question.  There are no ethernet jacks available.

We have a e2500 cisco linksys router and we would like to have this router connect to the offered wifi network, and have our router provide it's own wifi that we can connect to (is this a subnet?) I'm not sure what this process is called (maybe wireless bridging?) or if it's possible, which has made finding details about it difficult.

I've tried setting it up below but had no luck (I connect the router to my laptop and then go to 192.168.1.1):
1) Setup basic wireless settings
2) In Basic setup: set the connection type to "bridge mode"
3) Set ip address to: 172.20.1.101
4) Set subnet mask to 255.255.255.0
5) Set default gateway to: 172.20.1.1

I obtained the default gateway and subnet mask from "ipconfig" when connecting to the wifi network.

After I save the above settings and restart the router, I can connect to the wifi network provided by the E2500 but I have no internet connectivity.  Am I on the right path? I was hoping the captive gateway portal would come up like when connecting directly to the office wireless network.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is this router running DD-WRT?

Comment: One of the reason the people supplying the WiFi might be using a HTTP-based captive portal is to prevent use of routers and such.  you may wan to check with them before you go any further (to ensure you're not breaking any rules that may cause your office to end up with NO Internet ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Normal home routers, such as the one you have, only support wifi on the lan side. You need to setup wifi on the internet side. Your only option with that hardware is to install a custom firmware, such as mentioned dd-wrt, and make lots of hardcore configuration.